# How do I query JSON entities with spaces in attribute names?

Tags: apigee, usergrid

Is it possible to select and query JSON attribute names with spaces in them?

For example:

```
GET http://xyzz.com/appservices/xyzz/mycollection?ql=select data.sequences.Lifetime%20Referring%20Sources where data._id = 1234
```

Escaping with %20 in this case doesn't work.  Oh, I should mention that I have little control of the attribute names without doing a huge amount transformation.

Here is a snippet of how the data is stored:

```
"data":{
   "_id":1234
   "sequences":{
      "Lifetime Referring Sources":1
   }
}
```

Comment: are you trying to "query" JSON using SQL syntax?

Comment: Definitely don't recommend doing it with spaces, if it doesn't work with %20 you may be out of luck.

Comment: One other thing to try is the Unicode character code for space?

Comment: Could I better understand the problem if someone could point me to the part of usergrid is digesting this string?

Answer (score 0):

I tried every combination I could think of (First\x%20Name, "First Name", 'First Name', First%20Name, and First\ Name. None of them worked so I think you are out of luck.

The JSON spec does not specifically forbid spaces in the attribute names but it's not considered good practice for exactly this kind of reason -- translating a label into a variable gets tricky when there are spaces in the label

Comment: select data.sequences.["Lifetime Referring Sources"]  didn't work either.    How likely is it that any modern JSON parser is going to be able to handle this?